# Schedule background tasks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I'm currently working on an alarm application , and i am implementing a smart alarm feature where i have to fetch data from server to determine whether it is the right time to wake user up.

Let's say, the case is :

- Alarm set to 06:30AM
- Smart alarm feature set to 30 mins before 06:30 , which the data fetching will happens 5 times with 5 minutes interval starting from 06:00AM to 06:25AM
- If , let's say , at 06:15AM the server returned a data which is needed to wake the user up, all tasks scheduled will be cancelled immediately
- Current time is 11:30PM
- No smart alarm's tasks will be executed during the period of 11:30PM to 06:00AM

Comment: You cannot schedule background operations for a specific time on iOS.  For your scenario you would need a server to send push notifications to the device when required.

Comment: Paul speaks truth. Paul, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Orange did you find any work around??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Push Notifications / Silent Push Notifications to achieve this task.
Please note the user must opt-in for push notifications for this to work.
Here is an overview of how you can achieve it

- Whenever user set's an alarm send this time to server via a web-service.
- The server will send a push notification payload to APNS and it will redirect to App based on device token.
- Once the device receives notification payload a delegate will be called. You can process the data in this payload related to alarm or invoke a web service call.
- Use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to execute your 5 minute interval tasks. beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler request extra time from the OS to execute a task. It is not specified (intentionally) by Apple how long this extra time is, however in practice it is around 10 minutes.

Please read more in detail about: Push Notifications, Silent Push Notifications & background task handlers.

---

Background Fetch API : In iOS 7, Apple added support for background fetch—a kind of smart, per-app crontab that wakes up at opportunistic times. There is no way to force background fetches to execute at exact intervals. iOS checks how much data and battery power was used during previous background fetches when scheduling future callbacks.
Adding support involves editing your application’s property list (see UIBackgroundModes) and setting a fetch interval early in the app lifecycle

[More Details Here](https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/)

Comment: It is stated before ,  that the server won't be doing any push notification , as the server wasn't handled by us. So i have no choice but to do a repeated scheduled background check. But thanks for the detailed explanation.